# SQL Server Need To Run Same Query Multiple Times To Get Desired Results

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I had working perfectly on Wednesday but is no longer working properly. I haven't changed any of the code and for some reason it's just not acting the same way.

Here's the code snippet that isn't working:

```
WITH Minimum AS (SELECT DataTable.PortID, [Rating Max],
    CASE When [Rating Max] <= [Sector Max] And [Rating Max] <= [ConcAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= [NatAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= [CashMaxAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= MatAfterUnwritten And [Rating Max] <= MatAfterInitialConcentration  Then [Rating Max]
         When [Sector Max] <= [ConcAfterUnwritten] And [Sector Max] <= [NatAfterUnwritten] And [Sector Max] <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And [Sector Max] <= MatAfterUnwritten And [Sector Max] <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then [Sector Max]
         When ConcAfterUnwritten <= NatAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then ConcAfterUnwritten
         When NatAfterUnwritten <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And NatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And NatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then NatAfterUnwritten
         When CashMaxAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And CashMaxAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then CashMaxAfterUnwritten
         When MatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then MatAfterUnwritten
         Else MatAfterInitialConcentration
         End As [Min Of 5 Restrictions]
FROM DataTable)
UPDATE DataTable
Set 
    DataTable.MinOf5Restrictions = Minimum.[Min Of 5 Restrictions],
    DataTable.MktValueAllocation = IIF(Minimum.[Min Of 5 Restrictions] < DataTable.MatAfterInitialConcentration, 0, DataTable.MatAfterInitialConcentration),
    DataTable.ModelParAmount = IIf([MktValueAllocation]=0,0,Round([MktValueAllocation]/([$Px+Acc]*10)/5,0,1)*5),
    DataTable.AllocatedPar = IIF(DataTable.ModelParAmount = 0, 0, ParLots.AllocatedPar),
    DataTable.[Check Cash And Concentration] = IIf(DataTable.[AllocatedPar]*[$Px+Acc]*10>[MinOf5Restrictions],[ModelParAmount],DataTable.[AllocatedPar]),
    DataTable.[Final After State Switch] =  IIf([StateOnly]='TRUE',IIf([RestrictionType]='Specific',[Check Cash And Concentration],0),[Check Cash And Concentration])
FROM 
    ((DataTable INNER JOIN Minimum ON DataTable.PortID = Minimum.PortID) LEFT JOIN ParLots ON DataTable.ModelParAmount = ParLots.ModelPar) INNER JOIN TestSet ON DataTable.PortID = TestSet.PortID, Main;
```

My current problem is that I have to run the query 6 times in order to get the result that I want. Basically the UPDATE statement only seems to be updating one of the columns every time that I execute it instead of all 6 at once. The first time it's executed the MinOf5Restrictions is populated but the other columns aren't, the second time MktValueAllocation is populated but the last 4 are still empty, etc.

Any idea why this might be? I suppose I could separate it into 6 different UPDATE statements but I'd rather not if I don't have to, especially since I had it working before.

Thanks

Comment: You can add an `OUTPUT` clause to the `UPDATE` statement and see what is being updated in each pass. For testing you can wrap it in `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. That will allow you to rerun the query without actually updating the table.

Comment: I would recommend you to debug your query, part by part, specially all these inline ifs and the select case to be sure that they're returning the desired value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you have there is very complicated and without knowing schema of tables and values in tables it is hard to diagnose your issue. However that being said the way I typically debug issues with updates is modifying it to a select and seeing if the values returned are what you expect and what you would want to be updating. So I would update the query to something like this (couldn't verify that this works since I don't have schema but should give you an idea if it doesn't).

```
WITH Minimum AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DataTable.PortID
       ,[Rating Max]
       ,CASE 
            When [Rating Max] <= [Sector Max] And [Rating Max] <= [ConcAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= [NatAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= [CashMaxAfterUnwritten] And [Rating Max] <= MatAfterUnwritten And [Rating Max] <= MatAfterInitialConcentration  Then [Rating Max]
            When [Sector Max] <= [ConcAfterUnwritten] And [Sector Max] <= [NatAfterUnwritten] And [Sector Max] <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And [Sector Max] <= MatAfterUnwritten And [Sector Max] <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then [Sector Max]
            When ConcAfterUnwritten <= NatAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And ConcAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then ConcAfterUnwritten
            When NatAfterUnwritten <= CashMaxAfterUnwritten And NatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And NatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then NatAfterUnwritten
            When CashMaxAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterUnwritten And CashMaxAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then CashMaxAfterUnwritten
            When MatAfterUnwritten <= MatAfterInitialConcentration Then MatAfterUnwritten
            Else MatAfterInitialConcentration
         End As [Min Of 5 Restrictions]
    FROM DataTable
)
SELECT
    Minimum.[Min Of 5 Restrictions] [MinOf5Restrictions],
    IIF(Minimum.[Min Of 5 Restrictions] < DataTable.MatAfterInitialConcentration, 0, DataTable.MatAfterInitialConcentration) [MktValueAllocation],
    IIf([MktValueAllocation]=0,0,Round([MktValueAllocation]/([$Px+Acc]*10)/5,0,1)*5) [ModelParAmount],
    IIF(DataTable.ModelParAmount = 0, 0, ParLots.AllocatedPar) [AllocatedPar],
    IIf(DataTable.[AllocatedPar]*[$Px+Acc]*10>[MinOf5Restrictions],[ModelParAmount],DataTable.[AllocatedPar]) [Check Cash And Concentration],
    IIf([StateOnly]='TRUE',IIf([RestrictionType]='Specific',[Check Cash And Concentration],0),[Check Cash And Concentration]) [Final After State Switch]
FROM 
    ((DataTable 
    INNER JOIN Minimum ON 
        DataTable.PortID = Minimum.PortID) 
    LEFT JOIN ParLots ON 
        DataTable.ModelParAmount = ParLots.ModelPar) 
    INNER JOIN TestSet ON DataTable.PortID = TestSet.PortID
```

If you want any more help it would be helpful if you could simplify your query (and doing this might also help you find the issue).

Comment: Thanks for the help Warren. Though I haven't really found the problem as to why it wasn't working, your tip will definitely help me in the future. 

Oddly enough, if I split it into 6 separate UPDATE statements, it works how I want it to. I'm probably going to just keep it with the 6 update statements since the minimal performance hit of the multiple update statements is not worth the time or headache to try and fix.
I believe the problem is that the third column, ModelParAmount, is reading every column of MktValueAllocation in as 0, so it seems to be executing that statement before the other